# How do I disable list of suggested password shown in an `<InputText type="password">` field used in a razor component for all browsers

Tags: javascript, c#, html, razor, blazor

I am creating a razor component and it has following field

```
<InputText type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="New Password" name="password" id="newPw" autocomplete="off" />
```

When the build is executed and run in `Chrome`. I see a list of suggested passwords. I don't want this list to be shown. The image is given below

[Image of list of password being shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUMij.png)

How can I disable this? In `autocomplete` attribute. I have also used `new-password` but it still doesn't hide  the list

Regards

Saad Saeed

Comment: Why disable it though? It's a good feature to have.

Comment: Did you try autocomplete="current-password"? Doubt it would make a difference...perhaps one of the other [values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete)? There's a very long thread somewhere about people trying to disable this over the years and what works one day doesn't work with the next release of a browser (or cross-browser). But remember it's a usability feature for your users who may in fact want it! You may also want to add data-lpignore="true" which will stop lasspass from filling it. Also try autocomplete="dummy" or attributing the form instead

Comment: @DavidG Well I should have control over it. It doesn't make sense that I have to use it whether I want it or not.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Yes. I have tried both "current-password" and "dummy" in auto-complete. Both of them are not working. I also added data-lpignore="true" but still the issue remains. I have attributed form using auto-complete but issue remains.

Answer (score 1):

When Blazor components map to a specific html element such as `form` or `input` you can usually include html elements.

For a single input you can add `autocomplete="off"`

`<InputText autocomplete="off" ...other stuff.../>`

Or you can disable it at form level like so

`<EditForm autocomplete="off" ...other stuff...>`

Comment: Hello Peter. I have inserted the attribute `autocomplete="off"` in both `<EditForm>` and `<InputText>` but its not working. Another thing is there a `EditConext` tag in blazor?

Comment: EditContext  is not a component... You can't use it like this.

Comment: @saad if you right-click the page and select Inspect, do you see a `<form>` with `autocomplete="off" `? Also, which browser are you testing with?

Comment: @PeterMorris Yes. I do see its there. I am testing with `Google Chrome` version `83.0.4103.97`

Answer (score 1):

It's weird, I know.  If you give it an ID, it won't ask.

```
<InputText id="dummyid" type="password" class="form-control" 
           placeholder="New Password" name="password" id="newPw" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: You are right. I somehow missed that he already had an id in there.  Dunno then.

Comment: Also made a typo, it was: "It shall be a typo - having 2 ids for an element"

Comment: @Julia. This is not working. I am facing this problem again. Doing this doesn't hide the password list and I am also seeing the password manager firing up.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me `autocomplete="new-password"` specially on Microsoft Edge and inputs for login/passwords:

```
<InputText autocomplete="new-password" ...other stuff.../>
```